# Need to know the difference between the Bitmap's pixel format Format32bppArgb and Format24bppRgb

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue with .net controls while saving them as images.  when i export the Panel control as image with bitmap's Pixel format 'Format24bppRgb' then a Gray border is shown in the image but it is not shown when i export it using the pixelformat 'Format32bppArgb'. I dont know why the gray border is visible in the image. Can any one help me on this?

Here is the code which is used to export image:

```
 using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)panel1.Width, (int)panel1.Height,PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
        {
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                using (Brush brushFill = diagram1.Model.BackgroundStyle.CreateBrush(g, rect))
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(brushFill, Geometry.ConvertRectangle(rect));

                }

                bmp.Save(@"..//..//bitmap.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
```

Here is the image i have created with format Format24bppRgb
[image]

Here is the image i have created with format Format32bppArgb [image]

Thanks is advance........................

Comment: I assume you changed this line - `using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)panel1.Width, (int)panel1.Height,PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))` for the 32 bbp test.

Comment: Hard to guess what ConvertRectangle() does.  But surely it changes rect.  So you won't draw all of the bitmap pixels.  So part of the background pixels will be visible.  You didn't use g.Clear() to set them so they'll be black in 24bpp and transparent in 32bpp.  Use g.Clear() to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

`Format24bppRgb` is just the Red, Green and Blue values of each pixel. At 8 bits per colour you get 24 bits per pixel.

`Format32bppArgb` include an Alpha (or transparency) value for each pixel. This is an extra 8 bits per pixel so you get a total of 32 bits per pixel.

There's a border on the second image as well - it's seems to be a dotted and a lot fainter than on the first. This must be an artefact of the saving process and must be fainter in the second case because of the alpha channel.

Comment: Ok then why the gray border is shown while saving the control with Format24bppRgb.

Answer (score 1):

Format24bppRgb is `Red, Green and Blue` values of each pixel. At 8 bits per color (0 ~ 255)

Format32bppArgb is `Alpha, Red, Green and Blue` values of each pixel. At 8 bits per color (0 ~ 255). Alpha is for transparent effect. You can set `Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;` to get the transparent effect, show as the following pic:[image]